# Is this imperative sentence wrong: "Make sure you wouldn't use the stairs"?

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctive-mood, imperatives

In making a list of school rules, one of my students wrote the sentence "Make sure you wouldn't use the stairs." I feel that using the imperative "Make sure" followed by the modal verb "would't" is wrong, but I don't know of any rule that explicitly states this. Can anyone provide more information on this, please?

Comment: It's highly unusual, but I wouldn't say it's wrong. It seems like a simpler version of *make sure there isn't a situation where you would use the stairs*.

Comment: **1** I do not see a grammar issue here. **2** Semantically, it fails to make proper sense -- say "you do not" and be done with it. **3** Most importantly, I don't even think the poor kids would get the point, if there is any, in using a more complicated semantic or stilted phraseology.

Comment: It's valid in the right context.  But the above scenario does not appear to be the right context.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the use of ***would*** is wrong.  [This site](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+sure) gives you examples of how ***make sure*** is properly used.

**Make sure of + noun**:  *Make sure of your facts before proceeding.*

**Make sure (that)/to + verb**:  *Make sure (that) you collect your facts before proceeding. / Make sure to collect your facts before proceeding.*

Answer (score 0):

*Would*, like ‘*will*’ is a devilish little word.  Take the following examples.

> 1. When I was young, after school, I would go up to the heath with my friends to play football.
> 2. I warned you not to go near the electric fence, but you **would** just do it, wouldn’t you?
> 3. I wouldn’t go there if I were you.

These are all slightly different.

The reason is the association of *would* with *will*.  Sentence 3 is the true modal use in a the context of a remote conditional, referring to the future.  It is tempting to interpret the “wouldn’t” of the question in this way, as an apodosis with the protasis left to be understood.  But there is at least one alternative (not among my three examples!).

In sentence 1, *would*is functioning as a habitual past:  “... I **used to** go ...”.

In sentence2, the “**would** is a past of determination.  My use of **bold** reflects the fact that it only comes across when spoken with special emphasis on the word ‘*would*’.

But I suggest that the word ‘would’ is out of place in the context of the question.  There is a perfectly good admonitory imperative, introduced by *make sure* or *mind*.   But it goes

> Mind/make sure you **don’t** go near the electric fence.

What is the construction? Well, the context is modal, but the verb just is a simple present, as far as I can see.